# Broken package problem while installing open source AMD ATI drivers in 14.04

Tags: apt, 14.04, ati, dependencies, fglrx

After purging the `fglrx*` packages, I tried this -

```
ankit@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of libgl1-mesa-glx is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
Reinstallation of libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libdrm-intel1:i386 (>= 2.4.48) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (>= 2.4.31) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any solution around this?

Comment: See the answer by @neon_overload here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages. Fixing dependencies would be a good place to start.

Comment: Install graphic card drivers by `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-amd xserver-xorg-video-ati`